# Twilio masked number for calling

Tags: twilio, caller-id

We have a requirement like below:

Person A (like an Agent) want to call user B with masked number. User B sees masked number (not the real number of A) and B can also call back to Agent with the masked number. At B side, normal telephone needs to work.

So, our conceren is, can we able to use the masked phone number for Agent with a real phone number so that B can call back Agent ?

We considered the option, Caller ID for agent, but the caller id verification needs to be avoided in this use case.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We usually refer to these type of "masked" phone numbers as proxies.

Do agents call from a phone or using the [Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/voice-sdk)?

---

**If an agent calls from a phone.**

You could build an application with a Twilio Phone Number that the agent can call. When the agent calls, the application could ask the agent to enter the user's phone number using the [TwiML Gather verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-gather-user-input-via-keypad), then the application can [dial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) the entered phone number. As a result the user would see the Twilio Phone Number aka the proxy number, and not the agent's phone number. Depending on your needs, instead of asking for the user phone number, you could ask for the customer ID or other identifier that your application can lookup the user's phone number by. The user could call the proxy number, and your application could look up the associated agent's phone number from a database, and then dial the agent's phone number.

If you don't want the agent to enter a phone number or user identifier, you could [acquire a Twilio Phone Number programatically](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource?code-sample=code-provision-a-phone-number&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json) for each Agent/User combination, then store the agent phone number, user phone number, and proxy number into a database. When the proxy phone number is called by the agent, your application can dial the user's phone number, when the user calls the proxy number, your application can dial the agent's phone number. Technically, other agents and other users could also be assigned to this proxy number, but you wouldn't be able to assign the same agent or user to the same proxy number multiple times as you wouldn't know which agent/user to dial when called.

---

**If an agent calls using the Voice SDK.**

Using the Voice SDK could be a better experience for your agents and also simplifies the solution somewhat. When you initiate a call through the Voice SDK you can pass along extra parameters to your application. So say that you have a web application that lists the users, and every user has a "call" button, you could click the button and the user's phone number could be passed in as a parameter to your application. Your application can then instruct Twilio to dial the user's phone number. When the user calls the proxy number, you'd still need to look up the agent associated to the user in a database and [dial the agent's Client ID](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client).

Unfortunately, I can only suggest these high level solutions with the information you provided, but I can provide more instructions if you provide more details.

Comment: Yes, the first part we have tried and working. In this case, we assume that the proxy number is to be a twilio number that we purchased extra. What we are looking for a solution with masked number means the proxy number can be an office telephone number or any other telephone number that agent firm or user owns, means, it will not be a twilio number.

Comment: I'm struggling to grok this. You want the agent to call the real phone number with a normal phone, but the user needs to see the proxy number?

Comment: Suppose Agent is working for company C having office number C1. Agent registered with twilio with his mobile number M1 and when calling any user, user will see C1 as the calling number. Also, user can call back normally to the C1 office number without through twilio. Now, when we consider with twilio, since the number C1 is non-twilio, inorder to make C1 as caller number for agent, we have this number to be verified with twilio. We want the verification to be avoided or by some other means like silent verification / programatically verified but without getting any inputs from agent.

Comment: Agent just enter C1 number. So, we are looking like without agent inputs anything, can C1 be verified and use as caller id or it can be use like proxy number ?

Comment: Yes, if you add C1 as a verified caller ID, you'll be able to use it as the phone number that's calling the user via Twilio. However, this requires you to manually verify the caller ID as it will text or call the phone number.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the information. So, either we should verify the number to use as caller id or we need to purchase a number from twilio and use proxy / mask feature to use it as caller id.